# Windows Phone VoIP infrared sensor disable

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, voip, windows-phone-voip

I'm using the windows phone `VoIP API` to play audio from the receiver. By default the screen will be black when user close to the receiver.

How can I disable the infrared sensor and don't let screen being black?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. That sensor is set by default to work.

I know, it is weird, but the purposes are very well defined.

Comment: But I know some app made this happened actually.For example: WeChat. I didn't how to do it.

Comment: @Joel You mean proximity sensor?

Comment: I mean the one which let the screen black while making a phone call.